How to migrate Signal Messenger data from Android to iPhone?
So I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this but I'm getting zero replies from support@signal.org so I thought I'd check in with the online community.
I'm familiar with the security issues surrounding the "data" that Signal stores and that there is a master key that is used (created during installation) that is embedded into the Android phone and non-transferable.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to either utilize the backup function to get from Android to iOS (however without the key that seems unlikely) or to utilize the move function that was built for Android-to-Android moves.  I can find zero documentation on the function in the iPhone world.
I have found references to "decrypting the data" for movement (a long and difficult process given that it was never meant to be exported and therefore it is a non-trivial, highly manual process) but haven't seen anything practical.
Although this is a long shot, I'm just checking to see if anyone has successfully accomplished this either through some undocumented method that Signal built, or something less obvious.
Unfortunately, I have over 5GB of messages and attachments over a 6-year period that I don't want to "throw away".
(I've been digging around Stack Exchange to find the right place to post this and this one is the closest forum I've found so if it belongs elsewhere, let me know)

There's also [apple.se] for Apple products including iOS. You might want to check and post it there too, while also linking this question on there (and their question on here) to let both know of any progress if any of them has been answered.

Partial answer
There are many related questions you ask. I am attempting to answer in sequence, as asked



What I'm trying to figure out is how to either utilize the backup function to get from Android to iOS



Not possible as of now

Switching from Android to iPhone or vice versa - path to transfer backups? 2020 This issue is still open and from the discussion it appears, it will not be/not yet implemented.

But, it may be possible in near future since user names have been implemented (at least in Android)
Signal iOS from Android Migration 2022

No, there’s been no movement. As I said in April, there probably won’t be movement until after usernames which won’t be out until “early 2023”...



Caveat: See postscript at the end of answer.



utilize the move function that was built for Android-to-Android moves



Again not possible

Do I have to register to restore backup and view old messages? 2022


Your Signal messages can not be transferred from Android to iOS (or vice versa, for that matter). Furthermore, the iOS app does not support creating or restoring backups, unfortunately. You will be starting from a (mostly) clean slate, with the exception of your contacts and group memberships (assuming you were using and remember your Signal PIN)

(Emphasis supplied)



I have found references to "decrypting the data"



As you rightly surmised decryption is only for extracting data for reference. I am not sure how one can parse then and how to search for media. Decryption, therefore doesn't help in moving to iOS. Quick search reveals one method

Restore from Android to iOS


It is not currently possible to transfer messages from Android to iOS.
However there are 3rd party solutions that allow you to decrypt a Signal (Android) backup and therefore you can keep the messages in an encrypted backup and decrypt when you want to read them, or decrypt them all and keep them plaintext if you prefer.




Although this is a long shot, I'm just checking to see if anyone has successfully accomplished this either through some undocumented method that Signal built, or something less obvious.



I couldn't find any (that's why this is a partial answer). IMO, it is unlikely (debatable).
Given this situation, it appears your best bet would be to decrypt the Signal Database you have, store it on your iPhone and access it as needed. Signal on iPhone would be a clean slate, implying you would lose continuity in your chats but then the 5GB worth is at least not lost.

PS:
Lastly, Signal does not publish a road map, which means you won't know when this feature is to be implemented

The Signal team does not publish a public roadmap. The best we get is from following the commit logs of the respective projects (iOS, Android, Desktop, Server).


You have links to the forums that may come in handy and you can post your own answer once you find a way (maybe beta version?) //I am not migrating or planning to migrate to iOS, so would not be tracking developments//On a tangent, even rooted Android apps that backup and restore fail with Signal because the app uses Android keystone
